# python postgresql timezone

Tags: python, postgresql

Есть таблица, где в числе прочего есть колонка `created_at`, типа `timestamp default now()`.
Если делаю такой запрос из ide

```
insert into error_log(module_name, error_message)
select 'test','test'
```

То время проставляется корректное. Если вызывается эта функция:

```
def errorLog(module_name, error_message):
    error_message = (error_message[:250] + '..') if len(error_message) > 250 else error_message
    db = postgresql.open(db_conf.connectionString())
    insert = db.prepare("insert into error_log (module_name,error_message) values($1,$2)")
    insert(module_name, str(error_message))
```

То время создания записи -3 часа. Почему такая разница в поведении и как можно пофиксить?

Comment: IDE и Python скрипт запускаются с одного сервера/машины?

Comment: @MaxU Да, с одного.

Comment: А какой IDE вы используете?

Comment: @MaxU dbeaver использую. Все крутится на локальной машине

Comment: у меня единственное подозрение - `now()` возвращает тип данных `timestamp with time zone`, а у вас тип: `timestamp`. Похоже либо Python либо dbeaver пытается привести  `timestamp with time zone` к `timestamp`. Попробуйте либо поменять тип данных в столбце `created_at` либо использовать `localtimestamp()` который возвращает `timestamp` без `time zone` вместо использования `now()`

Comment: @MaxU localtimestamp() не дало изменений, а вот замена типа данных столбца с timestamp на timestampz решило проблему.  Спасибо. Если оформите в ответ, с удовольствием плюсану.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) возвращает тип данных `timestamp with time zone`, а у вас тип: `timestamp`. Попробуйте поменять тип данных в столбце `created_at` на `timestamp with time zone`.